# psycopg2 - Encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "LATIN1" even when set client_encoding

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to create a way to test a database restore with multiprocess but a simple connection not working. I tried a lot tutorials and answers but no success yet. There is my code:

```
def pyconn():
    con: connection = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname='XXXX',
        user='XXXX',
        password='XXXX',
        host='XXXX',
        port=5432
    )
    con.set_client_encoding('UTF8')
    return con


def read_sql(query):
    conn = pyconn()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    with open('NUL') as dev_null:
        cur.copy_expert("COPY (select XXX from XXXX limit 10) to '/dev/null'‬", dev_null)
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

I'm in a Windows machine and the database is in a Linux Server.

- I've tried the same script into the server: same error
- I run the command with psql -U XXX -d XXX -h XXX -c "COPY (select XXX from XXXX limit 10) to '/dev/null'‬": works!

The error that I got is

```
psycopg2.errors.UntranslatableCharacter: character with byte sequence 0xe2 0x80 0xac in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "LATIN1"
```

Could you help me?

Comment: The error is clear - you tried to treat a UTF8 string as if it were Latin1. Windows uses Unicode for strings natively (UTF16 specifically). The fact you get the *same* error on the Linux server means the problem is probably with the query itself - and that you set LC_LANG to UTF8. That byte sequence is an invisible [punctuation character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202c/index.htm). What is the *actual* query? Was the source file saved as UTF8? If not, no matter whether Python supports UTF8 or not (it does), the string itself *won't* contain what you thought it would

Comment: Hi, @PanagiotisKanavos. Thank you for your reply. I'm not sure if I understood what you said. The name of the table has punctuation character? The table name is some thing like xxx_xxxx_xxx. The same for database name (LATIN1). I saw that set client_encoding to UTF8 was enough but it is not working. The query is: COPY (select id_processo_documento_bin from tb_proc_doc_bin_p001 limit 10) to '/dev/null'

Comment: UTF8 isn't the same as LATIN1. The non-ASCII characters in Latin1 are encoded using *two* bytes in UTF8. The error complains about a character that's *outside* even the Latin1 range though, so it can't be translated to the server's character set (which shouldn't be Latin1 to begin with, to avoid exactly those problems)

Comment: Hi, @PanagiotisKanavos . Unfortunately I can't change the charset anymore. I can do the same command inside psql, but it's not working inside the script. How is it possible? Sorry, I really don't know what I'd do.

Comment: @jjanes Sorry for the indetation, it was wrong when i paste here but it's not the problem :(

Comment: If you just retype (not copy-paste!) your script code (SQL part), does error go away? I have seen strange characters in code, copied from dark places :)

Comment: Hi, guys. I can't believe it was that. Thank you @Arvo and everybody else. The problem was in Pycharm : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-1311?_ga=2.119544392.193898492.1590762722-1491663182.1584629353 . I rewrote the code in Visual Code and now it works like a charm.